# MySQL connection only works once in a while loop?

Tags: php, sql

**Given this code:**

```
<?php 
include 'dbconnect.php';
include 'properties_classes.php';

mysqli_select_db($connection, 'bl1property');
$p_results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM property");
$r_results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM rooms");

function return_bed_results($p_id, $r_results) {
    $total_bed = 0; 
    $available_single_bed = 0;  
    $available_double_bed = 0;
    echo ' Start searching for rooms at property ' . $p_id . '</br>';

    while ($bed_r = mysqli_fetch_array($r_results)) {
        echo 'str from ' . $bed_r['property id'] . '</br>';
        if ($p_id == $bed_r['property id']){
            echo 'pass (1) ' . $bed_r['property id'] . ' n ' . $bed_r['room no'] . '</br>';
            if ($bed_r['occupied'] == 0) {
                echo 'pass (2) ';
                if ($bed_r['room type'] == 'Single') {
                    echo ' single ' . '</br>';
                    $available_single_bed++;
                } else {
                    echo ' double ' . '</br>';
                    $available_double_bed++;
                }
            }
            $total_bed++;
        }
    }
    $return_b = new BedResults;
    $return_b->total_no_beds = $total_bed;
    $return_b->available_single_beds = $available_single_bed;
    $return_b->available_double_beds = $available_double_bed;
    echo '</br>' . 'Property no ' . $p_id . '</br>';
    echo 'No of beds = ' . $return_b->total_no_beds . '</br>';
    echo 'No of S beds = ' . $return_b->available_single_beds . '</br>';
    echo 'No of D beds = ' . $return_b->available_double_beds . '</br>';
    return $return_b;
}
$p_search_index = 0;
$newResults[] = new Results;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($p_results)) {
    if ($accomodation_type == $row['tenant type'] || $accomodation_type == 'any') {
        if ($living_arrangment == $row['arrangement'] || $living_arrangment == 'any') {
            if ($min_sel <= $row['rent_min'] && $max_sel >= $row['rent_max']) {
                $b_total = return_bed_results($row['id'], $r_results);
                $newResults[$p_search_index] = new Results;
                $newResults[$p_search_index]->total_Bed = $b_total->total_no_beds;
                $newResults[$p_search_index]->available_single = $b_total->available_single_beds;
                $newResults[$p_search_index]->available_double = $b_total->available_double_beds;
                $newResults[$p_search_index]->rent_min = $row['rent_min'];
                $newResults[$p_search_index]->rent_max = $row['rent_max'];
                $p_search_index++;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**The first loops works and it gives me data but afterwards .... nothing much happens!!**

**here is the output results:**

> Start searching for rooms at property 1 str from 1 pass (1) 1 n 1 str
>   from 1 pass (1) 1 n 2 str from 1 pass (1) 1 n 3 pass (2) double  str
>   from 1 pass (1) 1 n 4 str from 1 pass (1) 1 n 5 str from 1 pass (1) 1
>   n 6 str from 2 str from 2 str from 2 str from 2 str from 3 str from 3
>   str from 3 str from 3 str from 4 str from 4 str from 4 str from 4 str
>   from 7 str from 7 str from 7 str from 7 str from 7 str from 7 str from
>   8 str from 8 str from 8 str from 8 str from 8 str from 8 str from 8
>
> Property no 1 No of beds = 6 No of S beds = 0 No of D beds = 1 Start
>   searching for rooms at property 3
>
> Property no 3 No of beds = 0 No of S beds = 0 No of D beds = 0 Start
>   searching for rooms at property 4
>
> Property no 4 No of beds = 0 No of S beds = 0 No of D beds = 0 Start
>   searching for rooms at property 7
>
> Property no 7 No of beds = 0 No of S beds = 0 No of D beds = 0 Start
>   searching for rooms at property 8
>
> Property no 8 No of beds = 0 No of S beds = 0 No of D beds = 0
>
> **i dont know why only the first loops works... can some one help me please**
>   **Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Is perhaps the connection reset after the first loop? 
You might have to reopen it for the second query.

Coult you please post your dbconnect.php (obfuscated of course)

Edit: What happens when you add another mysqli_select_db statement like this?

```
mysqli_select_db($connection, 'bl1property');
$p_results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM property");
mysqli_select_db($connection, 'bl1property');
$r_results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM rooms");
```

Comment: $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root');
 if(!$connection ) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

Answer (score 0):

why do you do:

```
mysqli_select_db($connection, 'dbname');
```

try this:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','dbname');
```

if you password is nothing then you have to write NULL.

Comment: @Rickkwa i know, but why you select the db in this file but connect to the db in an other file?